# Synthesis of a multiplier design

Tags: verilog, multiplier

I have written a verilog code for a multiplier which gives correct results after simulation. But, the code generated after synthesis of the above mentioned code does not give correct results. In fact, it gives no results. The log file created after synthesis says that there could be possible timing errors with my design, although I have tried to synchronize everything at the positive edge of the clock. Besides, it also generates a warning which says:

> Variable or signal is driven in more than one process or block. This may cause simulation mismatches between the original and synthesized designs. [CDFG2G-622]
>           : 'qq[1]' in module 'ab_mac' in file '/ugassignments/ma3ps139/cadence/abacus8_syn/abacus8_chk.v' on line 59, column 22.

I don't know how to rectify this. Please help. Here is the code:

```
      module ab_mac (result, a, b, clk, reset, zero);
      output [16:1] result;
      input [8:1] a, b;
      input [11:0] zero;
      reg [8:1] A, B;
      input clk, reset;
      wire [16:1] p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
      reg [9:0] qq [16:1];
      reg [9:0] rr [16:1];
      wire [9:0] q [16:1];
      wire [3:0] ones [16:1];
      genvar j, i,  k, m;
      reg [4:0] count;

      part_prod_gen1 ppg (p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, a, b);

     //load the partial products
     generate
 for (j=1; j<=16; j=j+1)
 begin: loop1
  always @ (posedge clk)
  begin
  if (!reset)
  begin
    if (count == 5'b00000)
    begin
    qq[j][9] <= p7[j];
    qq[j][8] <= p6[j];
    qq[j][7] <= p5[j];
    qq[j][6] <= p4[j];
    qq[j][5] <= p3[j];
    qq[j][4] <= p2[j];
    qq[j][3] <= p1[j];
    qq[j][2] <= p0[j];
    qq[j][1] <= 1'b0;
    qq[j][0] <= 1'b0;
    end

  else if (count[0] == 1)
    begin
      qq[j] <= q[j];
    end

  else 
    begin
      case (ones[j])
      4'b0010 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8]} <= 2'b0;
          if (j<16) qq[j+1][9-ones[j+1]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b0011 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8]} <= 2'b0;
          if (j<16) qq[j+1][9-ones[j+1]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b0100 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8], qq[j][7],qq[j][6]} <= 4'b0;
          if (j<15) qq[j+2][8-ones[j+2]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b0101 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8], qq[j][7],qq[j][6]} <= 4'b0;
          if (j<15) qq[j+2][8-ones[j+2]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b0110 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8], qq[j][7],qq[j][6]} <= 4'b0;
          if (j<15) qq[j+2][8-ones[j+2]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b0111 : 
      begin {qq[j][9], qq[j][8], qq[j][7],qq[j][6]} <= 4'b0;
          if (j<15) qq[j+2][8-ones[j+2]] <= 1'b1; end

      4'b1000 : 
      begin {qq[j][9],qq[j][8],qq[j][7],qq[j][6],qq[j][5],qq[j][4],qq[j][3],qq[j][2]} <= 8'b0; 
          if (j<14) qq[j+3][7-ones[j+3]] <= 1'b1; end
      endcase
    end
end
end
end
   endgenerate

    //compress the partial products
      generate
      for (i=1; i<=16; i=i+1)
      begin: loop2
      count_one con (ones[i], qq[i]);
      shift sft (q[i], qq[i]);
      end
      endgenerate

assign result[1] = qq[1][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[2] = qq[2][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[3] = qq[3][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[4] = qq[4][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[5] = qq[5][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[6] = qq[6][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[7] = qq[7][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[8] = qq[8][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[9] = qq[9][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[10] = qq[10][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[11] = qq[11][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[12] = qq[12][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[13] = qq[13][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[14] = qq[14][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[15] = qq[15][9] & (!reset) ,
       result[16] = qq[16][9] & (!reset) ;

      always @ (posedge clk)
      if (reset)
      count <= 5'b00000;
      else
      begin
      count <= count + 1'b1;
      if(count == 5'b10001)
     count <= 5'b00000;
     end  

     endmodule
```

Also, here are the codes for the other instances in case you would like to verify:

```
    module shift (out, in);
    output[9:0] out;
    input [9:0] in;
    wire [3:0] ones;
    genvar i;
    count_one coon (ones, in);
    generate
    for (i=9; i>=0; i=i-1)
    begin: loop
    assign out[i] = (i > (9-ones)? 1 : 0);
    end
    endgenerate
    endmodule  

   module count_one (ones, column);
   output [3:0] ones;
   input [9:0] column;
   assign ones =    column[9]+column[8]+column[7]+column[6]+column[5]+column[4]+column[3]+column[2]+column[1]+column[0];
  endmodule

  module part_prod_gen (p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, in1, in2);
  output [15:1] p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
  input [7:0] in1, in2;
  wire [7:0] pp [7:0];
  genvar i, j;

  generate
  for (i=0; i<=7; i=i+1)
  begin: loop1
   for (j=0; j<=7; j=j+1)
   begin: loop2
   assign pp[i][j] = in1[j] & in2[i];
 end
 end
 endgenerate

 assign p0 = {7'b0, pp[0][7], 7'b0};
 assign p1 = {6'b0, pp[1][7], pp[1][6], pp[0][6], 6'b0};
 assign p2 = {5'b0, pp[2][7:5],pp[1][5],pp[0][5],5'b0};
 assign p3 = {4'b0, pp[3][7:4],pp[2][4],pp[1][4],pp[0][4],4'b0};
 assign p4 = {3'b0, pp[4][7:3],pp[3][3],pp[2][3],pp[1][3],pp[0][3],3'b0};
 assign p5 = {2'b0, pp[5][7:2],pp[4][2],pp[3][2],pp[2][2],pp[1][2],pp[0][2],2'b0};
 assign p6 = {1'b0, pp[6][7:1],pp[5][1],pp[4][1],pp[3][1],pp[2][1],pp[1][1],pp[0]   [1],1'b0};
 assign p7 = {pp[7][7:0],pp[6][0],pp[5][0],pp[4][0],pp[3][0],pp[2][0],pp[1][0],pp[0][0]};
 endmodule
```

Comment: @Xcodo, I have posted the remaining parts of the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: You can use for loops inside a process in Verilog (or VHDL), the syntax is the same as in C. However it's only synthesisable if the loop condition is constant at compile time, that is that the loop variable is being incremented up on down to a fixed value, either a numeric constant or a module parameter. In hardware this is equivalent to multiple copies of the circuit in parallel (like generates). Just be careful to ensure that none of the iterations rely on the result of another iteration in the same clock cycle or you will get a chain of the circuits rather than a parallel set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you are synthesising for an FPGA or CPLD. The simulator will successfully simulate many language constructs which are technically valid Verilog, but are very hard to translate to real programmable logic hardware.

I can't synthesise your block myself as I don't have the part_prod_gen1, count_one and shift modules available, but the problems I can see from reading the code are:

- Using posedge and negedge always@ blocks for signals other than clock and reset lines often isn't synthesisable (see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/26505/26659)). I think that using shift registers (explicitly or with a signal_old register) is a much more reliable approach than testing for posedge of count[0].
- Register array qq elements are assigned in multiple separate processed (always blocks). This is not synthesisable as the process blocks run in parallel and the register flip-flop cannot be set from two different sources. You can rectify this by combining much of the code into a single sequential process (which is ugly and harder to debug) or using intermediate wires which are combined together in a single process. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/29603/26659) for a similar problem.

  ```
  genvar j, i,  k, m;
  // ... other code
  //load the partial products
  generate
    for (j=1; j<=16; j=j+1)
    begin: loop1
      always @ (posedge clk)
      begin
        if (!reset) begin
        // ... qq assignments
        end
      end
    end
  endgenerate

  /* should be */

  genvar i,  k, m;
  integer j; // j as integer not genvar
  // ... other code
  //load the partial products
  //generate // comment out or remove
  always @ (posedge clk)
  begin
    for (j=1; j<=16; j=j+1) // <- for-loop inside always block
    begin: loop1
      if (!reset) begin
      // ... qq assignments
      end
    end
  end
  //endgenerate // comment out or remove
  ```

Comment: I have modified the design as per the changes u suggested. It still does not give the desired results.

Comment: Do you have any synthesis warnings now? I'm just having a look with the extra modules, I'll see what I can do in the next 10 minutes...

Comment: yes, I have the synthesis warnings as i did before. I will post the updated code shortly

Comment: I have posted the updated code. The warning is generated when qq[16:1][9] is assigned to result from qq[2][9] onwards

Comment: I've found the source of that. In the case statement based on ones[j] you assign values to qq[j+1]. In the simulator or on paper try to step through that logic to find out what you're actually assigning each time. Make sure for any condition each qq[][] bit is only assigned once per clock cycle. I'm afraid I have to go do some work so won't be able to look again until tonight. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I stepped through the logic on paper but did not find any conflicting assignments to qq[][] for any clock cycle! Besides my code is giving correct results on simulation prior to synthesis, so there can't be a problem with the logic. Regardless, it is not giving correct results after synthesis, so I guess I have to find an alternate way.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that j was still in a generate statement (I'm not doing badly since I haven't used Verilog in about five years, only VHDL!) Move the j to a for loop INSIDE the always block and it will at least synthesise.

Comment: For clarification - the generate statement is just a convenient shorthand for writing the always@ process 16 times. In each of those blocks there is a possibility (the synthesiser isn't too smart) that the process could write to a given qq register, so it is given as a driver. All of these generated processes then have a claim on driving the output, which isn't synthesisable.

Comment: @Xcodo, good debug. I added a code example of second bullet to be more specific.

Comment: Yes thank you @Greg, probably what I should have done all along!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Xcodo! But again the problem arises that moving the j to a for loop inside the always block will make my assignment to qq[][] sequential rather than concurrent, won't it? I mean to say, will doing this update the entire array qq[][] in one clock cycle?

Comment: @titan, It will be all done in one clock cycle. There are no delay elements in the always block. The for-loop will execute in zero time.

Comment: Many thanks @Xcodo for your help! My code synthesized.

Comment: Very happy to help. Feel free to tag me again if it all goes wrong!